# What is the largest linear system of equations solved using HHL experimentally?

Tags: hhl-algorithm

Can someone tell what is the largest system of equations solved using HHL algorithm experimentally?

I know the $8$ x $8$ system has been solved experimentally. Has someone gone beyond this to solve $16$ x $16$ or $32$ x $32$ or beyond?

If yes please provide the resource link and also mention the number of qubits used to design the circuit.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a paper where 8x8 system is solved?

Comment: @MartinVesely I think it’s [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.03295.pdf) one.